# Access Saved/Bookmarked Posts

Tags: support, search, bookmarks, saves

Since bookmarks are now saves, how can we access the saves in the search bar?

Earlier there was a way to access bookmarked items, like this `inbookmarks:mine` in the search bar i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inbookmarks%3Amine

Now it returns ~ 57,162,405 many results and not the bookmarked/saved items.

First of all, is this a regression/bug, and secondly, how can we access bookmarked items with the new Saves feature in the search box?

Comment: Related on Meta.StackExchange: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The help center for [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) has been updated, and the syntax is now `in:saves`.

> #### User Operators
>
> You can also limit searches to a specific user's content (your own or someone else's). You will need the user id to search another user's posts.
>
> - `user:mine` or `user:me` [...]
> - `in:saves` returns posts that you have saved
> - `intags:mine` [...]